# make a new connection with Oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, ioerror

I know this question has been asked frequently. However, none of the answers from them worked for me. So, I am posting the question. I tried to make a new connection in sql developer using my Oracle account's username and password that I used while trying to download the oracle software. However, it gives me an IO Error whenever I use those details. I tried options like "system" in username and the password of Oracle account. However, it still is not working.

help would be appreciated.

[image: It gives me this message every time I try to log in.]

Comment: What is your operating system and Oracle's version ? I am guessing it is linux. Does it meet [Operating System Requirements for Oracle Database 11g Release 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCHGDIE) or [Operating System Requirements for x86-64 Linux Platforms for Oracle Database 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LTDQI/toc.htm#BABBCJAA) ?  If not, then it could be problem with the installation.

Comment: Yes it is linux, ubuntu 17.1.0 and the Oracle's version is 17.4.0.

Comment: That is the version of your SQL Developer client. What version is you database *server*? Have you acually installed that too? It sounds like you’re trying to use credentials for your oracle.com account, which are nothing to do with database credentials.

Comment: yeah that is what I did. I think I haven't set the database server. I wonder how can i do that?

Comment: An installation manual is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04). It's for Ubuntu 14 but should work for 17 too. The database can be downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html). I vote to close this question.

Comment: https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really trying to connect to a local database with your oracle ´s website account?

You need to get a valid username/password from the guy who has installed the database on your local computer

If it is you, then you provided a password for the « system » user during install

Edit :

How did I miss it! Your current issue is not about an invalid login/password if it was you would get an « invalid username » message.

The message you get is « could not establish connection ». This message means the database « orcl » is not accessible on localhost:1521.

You must:

- create the database orcl, if not already done
- configure a listener to make the database accessible

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/network.htm#ADMQS0411

Comment: I don't actually remember doing that. Is there a way to find out the password and username?

Comment: The system password is needed to administrate other users. If it is lost, uninstall oracle dB and install it again. Before that, try again with user: system and an empty password

Comment: Actually, you do **not** need a listener to access locally installed database.